# Como redimensionar o tamanho da fonte - WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

O código a seguir funciona com `winforms`:

```
while (label1.Width < System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(label1.Text,
    new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size, label1.Font.Style)).Width)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size - 0.5f, label1.Font.Style);
}
```

Como posso fazer isso em WPF ? A ideia é fazer um `autoresize` num `textbox` até caber todas as palavras.

Segue a imagem a seguir, que na última linha foi cortada, quero diminuir o tamanho da fonte até mostrar todas as palavras.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A foto acima não é um `label`, é um `textbox`.

Alguma ideia de fazer em WPF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma [ViewBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.viewbox?view=netframework-4.7.1) para auto redimensionar o tamanho da fonte.

Exemplo

```
<Viewbox>
     <TextBox Text="TESTE"/>
</Viewbox>
```